# How to search stream for string in node.js?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, search, stream

How does one search for a string in a stream and then print it? By this I mean with the use of `createReadStream`. I figured out how to find strings in `readFile` with the use of `indexOf`, but I am reading that using streams are more efficient.

More specifically, I've been trying to find a string within a stream, and then print out the whole line that contains the string. However the following keeps giving me errors

```
fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2], function (err, data) {
      data.indexOf ...
```

Currently, my program prints out the entire stream rather than just the lines containing the strings.

```
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

console.log("Request received.");

res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
res.write("Hello World\n\n\n");

var s = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]).pipe(res); 

s.on('end', function(){ res.end() }) 


});
server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams are buffered, so the buffers passed to the `data` event (which you would normally listen to) aren't in any way split into, or delimited on, separate lines.

You can use the [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to perform line-by-line searching:

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var readline  = require('readline');

var server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
  console.log("Request received.");

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.write("Hello World\n\n\n");

  readline.createInterface({
    input     : fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2]),
    terminal  : false
  }).on('line', function(line) {
    var idx = line.indexOf(THE_SUBSTRING);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      res.write(line + '\n');
    }
  }).on('close', function() {
    res.end();
  });
});
```

(**EDIT:** readline strips newlines, so `res.write` adds one back)

Comment: This works great! I was wondering if there is an easy way to print out every line where the substring is found? Currently, it can only print out the first line of each unique substring it finds.

Comment: @krikara hmm it matches every line for me; however, it outputs them all on one line because `readline` strips the newline, see my edit for a fix.

Comment: Yeah that is weird. Perhaps it is because I am running my node from Windows CMD. I do have the latest stable npm and node installed though. I'm going to try my luck with the module below.

Comment: Oh actually I found the problem. It doesn't find the res.write the substring if the substring is on the very last line of the .txt file. Otherwise it works.

Comment: @krikara I think the file doesn't end with a newline, in that case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this module](https://github.com/mscdex/streamsearch) to search string in a stream without buffering